# What is the correct solution for the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty} x \sin\frac1x$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = ?$$

Not a long ago I saw this function, and I was curious, what limit it has, when $x$ approaches $\infty$? Some of my friends said fast that it must approach $\infty$, since $\sin$ is a bounded function, and $x$ goes to infinity, therefore infinity * bounded must be infinity. Some others said that $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ is $0$, since $\frac{1}{x}$ is $0$, when $x \rightarrow \infty$.

So, the first possible solution should be $\infty$, but here is an other one. Let $y=\frac{1}{x}$. If $x \rightarrow \infty$, then $y \rightarrow 0$. Using that:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \lim_{y\to 0} \frac {1}{y} \sin(y) = \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\sin(y)}{y}  = 1$$

Here is a proof that, $\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\sin(y)}{y}  = 1$: [Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)

So here we have $2$ completely different solutions for the same task, which both seem "logical". Is any of them correct, or if not, what should be the solution? Is this convergent, or divergent? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Using L'Hospital's Rule on $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\sin y}{y}$ is circular reasoning, because the derivation of $\sin'(x)$ usually uses that limit.

Comment: @user236182, although true, I don't think it's the main concern here.

Comment: @frank000 I never said it was the main concern, but it's faulty reasoning, so I'm pointing it out, so that they know.

Comment: The last one is correct. Recall as $x\to \infty$, $1/x \to 0$ and $\sin (1/x) \sim 1/x$.  Thus, $x\sin(1/x)\sim x(1/x) =1$.

Comment: Why infinity*bounded must be infinity? $\lim_{x\to \infty} x\cdot 0=0$.

Comment: I edited the question with the limit rule I used, but @frank000 is right, that is not the main question, thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: Dr. MV is correct. Your friends are mistaken in saying that $\infty$*bounded = $\infty$. $0$ is bounded, and $\infty$ * $0$ is indeterminant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first line of reasoning is clearly incorrect:  let $f(x) = x$, $g(x) = (x^2 + 1)^{-1}$.  Then $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$$ and $g(x) \in (0,1]$ is clearly bounded on $\mathbb R$.  But $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) g(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x+1/x} = 0.$$

Answer (score 8):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty }x\sin \frac{1}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty }\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\sin(u)}{u}=1$$

Comment: So that means, that the second solution is correct, thanks!

Comment: This answer is a copy of OP's second solution.

Comment: not $0$, need to be $0^+$. (Since limit exists, it is okay but not clear).

Answer (score 6):

$\infty\times\text{bounded}$ is not always $\infty$. You provide an example in your question. As $y\to0$, $1/y\to\infty$ and $\sin y$ is bounded. But $(1/y)\sin y\to1$.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's worth mentioning $\infty\times 0$ is an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form), which is why we can't determine the limit just by knowing it's of this form.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to see is

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x\sin{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to \infty} x\{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{3!x^3}+\frac{1}{5!x^5}-\cdots\}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\{1-\frac{1}{3!x^2}+\frac{1}{5!x^4}-\cdots\}=1$$

Comment: This uses Taylor series, which requires knowing $\sin'(x)$. It's circular reasoning, because finding $\sin'(x)$ usually uses $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Comment: @user236182 Why can't we take knowledge of $\sin' x $ for granted? We are not computing $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$ here, but solving a different problem.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: that is exactly what you are calculating here, in a slightly disguised form

Comment: @Henry No, it is not the same problem. This is an **exercise**. It is crucial that one does not use circular arguments while developing and explaining the theory. But exercises and problems can take for granted the full theory explained in a textbook, since it is already existing and proved in a self-consistent way (unless this is one of those contrived "compute this limit without using..." exercises, in which case OP should have specified it). All proofs in this thread use the known result  $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$, and there is no reason to avoid it in an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

You faced here an [indeterminate form](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form). It means that

$$0\cdot\infty$$

may be equal to $0$, $\infty$, any other number or may not exist at all. In this case it equals $1$.

Comment: Please explain why downvotes

Comment: I did not downvote, but people who read it quickly may read it as $0\cdot \infty=1$ and gave you a downvote.